# Is it possible to "override the method under view as creating view by inflater?"

Tags: android, layout-inflater

For Android development, I've done some research. I can't find any information about override the method under view as creating view by inflater.

The only thing I can find is ["setFactor"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#setFactory(android.view.LayoutInflater.Factory)) and ["setFilter"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#setFilter%28android.view.LayoutInflater.Filter%29). But it looks like not be able to override method.

For example, if I want to override the method [onDetachedFromWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDetachedFromWindow()), I could only override it by creating the view programmatically in Java code.

It seems like a native behaviour of Android layout inflater not able to override methods.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: what method do you want to override?

Comment: Are you used to program by python or ruby and so on?

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve by "override the method under view creating view by inflater"

Comment: Sorry about my implicit description, I should explain it much more precisely. I've edited my question. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: you can override some method when you create a custom class extending some base class, so use that custom View class in your layout xml file

Comment: @pskink, dude, that's a very smart and elegant approach. Sorry about that my dummy brain didn't come up with that. Thank you!! 

My issue could be perfectly resolved by that approach. However, I would still like to know, is this the only way to override the method since there's really no approach to override under layout-inflator infrastructure.

Please kindly paste the approach under answer, I would like to approve that. Thanks!!

Comment: So you want to dynamically override a method in an existing class without modifying the class itself? Java does not support that directly. There are some hacky approaches such as dynamically creating subclasses and overriding the method there, and then using the inflater factory to inject that code in place. But first review what you really want to achieve by overriding the method - there are probably easier ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: of course you can use LayoutInflater.Factory[2] interface when creating your View hierarchy, but this is more or less the same as using default LayoutInflater

Comment: @laalto Thanks for your detailed explaining, it's very helpful. Yeah, I think it does make sense that inflator is not able to override method since Java structure doesn't allow that. Guys you are all so helpful, thanks all of you very much.

Comment: I've edited your title. See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/130208/158100) where the consensus is "no, they should not".